# Walls separating only on one side of print bed

Tags: troubleshooting, creality-ender-5, delamination

Whenever I print, the walls separate when genial pressure is applied, this only happens to one side of the print, the side that faces the rear of the printer. I'm using 5 walls, so it’s only truly noticeable on the outer most walls, I’m sure it continues if I peel away more layers (the walls are printed first, then the infill). The print still looks “okay” so I only found out this issue after post-processing a prior print.

I’ve re-leveled the build plate and confirmed it with a bed visualizer.

I have attempted to shim that side of the print bed up.

I installed new belt tensioners to rule out belt tension.

I’m not sure what else to do, I rather not increase my flow or E-steps as the print dimensions are already pretty good and I don’t want to risk over extruding to solve my issue despite how it would fix the problem. I would be sacrificing accuracy for print coherency then.

- I print on an Ender 5 plus
- Slicer is Cura
- Print speed is 60 mm/s
- Printing at 220 °C for the hotend
- Filament is Makerbot PLA

Comment: Does an external temperature measurement of the heater block verify it is within 10 °C of that indicated by the printer?

Comment: Yes I did , it’s within specs

Comment: Is there something causing that side to be cooler: a fan blowing on that side or the bed heating is uneven?

Comment: Well I “ upgraded “ the oem fan shroud with a ring one Instead, ideally hitting the print with air from all sides.  I was having this problem with the oem fan shroud as well.

Comment: Try printing with cooling off to see if it's a cooling issue or something else.